# '.' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
template <class T>
struct stkNode
{
    BinTreeNode<T> *ptr;
    enum tag {R,L}tag;
    stkNode(BinTreeNode<T> *N = NULL) : ptr(N),tag(L){}
};

template<class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::PostOrder(void(*visit)(BinTreeNode<T> *p))
{
    SeqStack<stkNode<T> > S;
    stkNode<T> w;
    BinTreeNode<T> *p = root;
    do
    {
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            w.ptr = p;
            w.tag = w.L;
            S.Push(w);
            p = p->leftChild;
        }

        bool continuel = true;
        while (!S.IsEmpty() && continuel)
        {
            S.Pop(w); 
            p = w.ptr;

            switch (w.tag)
            {
            case w.L: //---------------this line--------------------------
                w.tag = w.R;
                S.Push(w);
                continuel = false;
                p = p->rightChild;
                break;
            case w.R: // -----------and this line-------------
                visit(p);
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (!S.IsEmpty());
}
```

When i compile it on Devc++, it will be an error looks like:
[Error] '.' cannot appear in a constant-expression.
But when i compile it on Visual Studio 2015,the error will not happen.
Why??????

-----------update my problem--------------------
such as

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct exp
{
    char ch;
    enum dir{
        L,R
    }direction;
    exp(char name,dir d){
        ch = name;
        direction = d;
    }
};
int main()
{
    exp t('a',exp.L); //this line
    return 0;
}
```

it was the same

Comment: This code is incomplete and does not compile at all. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I've updated it.

Comment: The second example is different and can be fixed by using the scope operator `exp::L`. In the first case you have a variable to the left of the dot, in the second case it is a type.

Comment: Your access method of enum is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i access method of enum wrongly....
   The right Code is:

```
template<class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::PostOrder(void(*visit)(BinTreeNode<T> *p))
{
    SeqStack<stkNode<T> > S;
    stkNode<T> w;
    BinTreeNode<T> *p = root;
    do
    {
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            w.ptr = p;
            w.tag = w.L;
            S.Push(w);
            p = p->leftChild;
        }

        bool continuel = true;
        while (!S.IsEmpty() && continuel)
        {
            S.Pop(w); 
            p = w.ptr;
            switch (w.Tag)
            {
            case stkNode<T>::L:
                w.tag = w.R;
                S.Push(w);
                continuel = false;
                p = p->rightChild;
                break;
            case stkNode<T>::R:
                visit(p);
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (!S.IsEmpty());
}
```

Comment: Side node: you marked your question with the `c++11` tag, there's some non-C++11 in your code. E.g.: old-style function pointers (instead of `std::function<void(BinTreeNode<T> *)>`) and `NULL` instead of `nullptr`.

Comment: you tagged C++11 so you can use `decltype()`: instead of `case stkNode<T>::L:` you can use `case decltype(w)::L`. It's the same thing but (IMHO) in some circumstances, can be clearer to read.